# Ubuntu repositories for Ubuntu Bash in Windows 10

Tags: bash, repository, windows-10

Can I use Ubuntu repositories or in general repositories we use in Ubuntu in Windows 10 Ubuntu Bash?

Answer (score 2):

It has `apt-get` and it uses the same commands we know in Ubuntu. So yes, but with limited functionality: the default setup does not have a desktop ([unofficially you can though](http://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/); the link has examples on installing `gvim` using `apt-get` but that also has its limits). So any application that is not a command line tool is pretty useless in the default setup.

[Example](http://daverupert.com/2016/04/jekyll-on-windows-with-bash/) installing ruby on bash on windows:

```
$ apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
$ apt update
$ apt install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev ruby-switch
```

Comment: Ok, I understand. But if I want to install Apache as a http server? or the newest php?

Comment: http://www.howtogeek.com/261575/how-to-run-graphical-linux-desktop-applications-from-windows-10s-bash-shell/ :)